# How to find out command in unix for files old than 5 days?

Tags: shell, unix

I am creating a shell script and as a requirement need the command for this.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far. If you have no clue first google it and get some demo code, try that, update that and still if you find any issues, post with your research here.

Answer (score 0):

No sure what you mean exactly by *old then 5 days*, but look up the `find` command, in particular the `-atime` operator of this command. Perhaps this is what you are looking for.